# global variable V.S. file variable in C++

Tags: c++, global-variables

what is the difference between global variable and file variable in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: excuse, my ignorance but I come from a a mainly C/Objective C background and I've never heard of a file variable...
Do you mean a global variable that is only visible in the file it is defined?

Comment: clarify: I assume you mean whether or not the keyword "static" is used? (static global vars are only visible in that file)

Answer (score 20):

In C and C++ you can make a global variable only accessible from the file in which it's declared by using the static keyword in front of the declaration.  Globals that don't use the static keyword are accessible from any C or C++ file compiled into the program.

The static global method is deprecated in C++ in favor of anonymous namespaces.  Any declarations placed inside an anonymous namespace are also only accessible from within that file.

Comment: is that valid for user defined classes as well? I have declared an object in file1 and I want to access it in both files (file1, file2) ,
I've put `#include file2.h` in file1 ,and 'class ClassName;`in file2
  so it recognize the class .. but still it gives me an error!!

Answer (score 7):

C++ programs are compiled one translation unit at a time (basically this means that each .cpp file is compiled independently).

By default, variables that are not `const`, functions that are not `inline` and `typedef`s have *internal linkage*: this means that they are not visible to other translation units. If other translation units refer to a symbol having internal linkage (after *declaring* it, which requires the keyword `extern` for variables), the linker won't be able to find them.

To explicitly require internal linkage use the keyword `static` or, better, use unnamed namespaces.

Answer (score 6):

*Note:* These rules apply to C++ just as well as C, with some dealings with class/struct/namespace scoping.  (I did not notice the question was about C++, not C.)

Remember that (in most cases) C source files are compiled into object files.  Object files have an 'export' table which tells the linker (when linking) what symbols it provides.  A symbol is a name (its exact name depends on the ABI) referring to a function or variable (in most cases).

When you declare a global variable in your C source file, like this:

```
// fileA.c
int hello = 42;

void printMessage() {
    printf("Hello, %d world(s)!\n", hello);
}
```

`hello` and `printMessage` are exported.  When a C object file requests a symbol called '`hello`' (assuming a simple ABI), the linker connects that with the `hello` exported by `fileA.c`.

Now for the other case.  When you declare a file-local variable like this:

```
// fileB.c
static int world = 9001;

static void messagePrint() {
    printf("It's over %d!\n", world);
}
```

`world` and `messagePrint` are *not* exported.  When a C object file requests a symbol called '`hello`', the linker cannot connect that with the `hello` of `fileB.c` because there is no information about it in `fileB.obj` (or whatever).

How can `messagePrint` know about `world`, though?  Both are in the same translation unit.  Scope takes over here.  I'm sure you'll find lots of information on [scope through Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+programming+scope).

(Is having the symbol name match the function/variable name standard in C?  I know it differs for C++ (where there is no standardization for name mangling), which is why I mention ABI in the first place.)

((If ABI the correct term, even?  ;P))

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that file variables are only accessible inside the file. But they have the same life time.